# Firefox back button works only the first time, not the second time

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, forms

I have a website where you can search on stuff with dates and more.
When I post the form I get to a result-page, when I hit the back button
I go back to my search-page and will refill the values.
This works in IE and FF.

however, whatever I do, when I search and go back again **the second time**, the values are lost in Firefox, while IE and other browsers still remember the filled-in values.
whatever I do on the search-page, it doesn't rememeber the new state, but only the original first-state.
Even when I check teh form-values before posting it, it shows the correct-values,
but when returning it is lost.

Comment: FF may be caching the output, and that may be the reason you are not getting your desired effect. But why do you want to do something like that? Instead why not pass the search strings & parameters in query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

I made a clean testcase without all the extra stuff I have and came to the simple conclusion it the # that caused the confusion and my problem.

when you do

```
<a href="#" onclick="DoSomethingFirstBeforeSubmittingTheForm()">Go!</a>
```

Firefox goes back to the .html variant of the page, while IE goes back to the .html# variant of the page.

while when you do

```
<a href="javascript:DoSomethingFirstBeforeSubmittingTheForm()">Go!</a>
```

both FF and IE go back to the html-page, and using the correct-cache.

Comment: Add "return false;" to the end of your function, it'll stop the link from performing it's action